# Перенос аккаунтов

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно реализовать перенос аккаунтов из одной базы данных на другую? 
Пользователь регистрирует новый аккаунт, и вводит свои старые данные для восстановления содержимого старого аккаунта (т.е восстановление по желанию). Нужно не только перенести все его данные, но и комментарии, логи действий и прочее.

Comment: давайте структуру БД или саму БД, тогда будем говорить о чем то. Это то же самое, что я вас сейчас прошу: где мой второй носок?

Comment: обычный mysqldump проблему не решает?

Comment: согласен с @mountpoint

уточните детали задачи, т.к. с текущим описанием ничего не понятно, слишком все абстрактно

Answer (score 0):

[Версионная миграция структуры базы данных: основные подходы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/121265/) - не подойдет?

Comment: Нет, но спасибо за полезную статью :)